# JavaFX: Aligning multiple ImageViews in an ordered, bindable fashion

Tags: javafx

I'm creating a Go-like program and have the board created, but I am stuck on how to align the positions where the pieces can be placed. My current plan is to have a grid of 19 by 19 empty ImageViews. When hovered over, those ImageViews will change their Image to translucentStone.png, and when a stone is placed in the location it will change the Image to blackStone.png or whiteStone.png.

[image: The current state of the application]

With all the ImageViews set to translucentStone.png the board should look like so:
[image: A representation of how the board should look covered in stones]

I've attempted to use a GridPane to align all these ImageViews properly as it logically seems to be the best option, however I can't get the ImageViews to line up properly with the linesBoard.png (this image is the black lines contained on the game board). It gets even worse when I try to bind the GridPane so it will grow/shrink appropriately with the gamesBoardPane or linesBoard objects when the application window changes size.

Another possible problem I see is that ImageView's can't be aligned based on their center x and y, so I'm not sure if that will prevent this behavior from being achieved.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Gomoku extends Application{

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    StackPane gameBoardPane = new StackPane();

    ImageView woodBoard = new ImageView("image/woodBoard.png");
    ImageView linesBoard = new ImageView("image/linesBoard.png");
    Image translucentStone = new Image("image/translucentStone.png");
    Image whiteStone = new Image("image/whiteStone.png");
    Image blackStone = new Image("image/blackStone.png");

    woodBoard.fitHeightProperty().bind(gameBoardPane.heightProperty());
    woodBoard.fitWidthProperty().bind(gameBoardPane.heightProperty());

    linesBoard.fitHeightProperty().bind(gameBoardPane.heightProperty()
        .multiply(.9));
    linesBoard.fitWidthProperty().bind(gameBoardPane.heightProperty()
        .multiply(.9));

    gameBoardPane.getChildren().addAll(woodBoard, linesBoard);

    Scene scene = new Scene(gameBoardPane, 1000, 600);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Gomoku");
    primaryStage.getIcons().add(whiteStone);
    primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I can upload the image files I'm using if needed.

Comment: I would just manage the layout entirely myself for something like this: i.e. use a `Pane`, not a `StackPane`, and call `setLayoutX(...)`, `setLayoutY(...)` on each element. If you're really drawing lines and circles, then I would use `Line`s and `Circle`s, not images at all (but perhaps you have more sophisticated images, particularly for the "stones").